# progress cursor after PNaCl was loaded

Tags: google-nativeclient

When loading a page that uses native client, the cursor turns into 'progress' for 5-6 seconds. This does not correlate to the actual loading progress as I receive the 'loadend' event a lot quicker (after less than 1sec).

I would like to know what does that represent, if anything?
Can I fix that and show the default cursor instead?

Setting the cursor to default on body didn't work.

**Edit:** This seems to happen only on windows. Mac and Ubuntu work fine.
Possibly a chrome/windows bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does seem like "a chrome/windows bug", so it could be worth filing at crbug.com (and tag with label Cr-Platform-NaCl).

The chrome NaCl loading code/implementation does not actively do anything to cause the busy cursor to spin after loadend as far as I know.